# Facebook Matching API - Returns empty data for any other user

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have a problem when I use the Facebook Checkbox Plugin in order to connect my users to a Facebook chatbot. When they click and the checkbox is checked, I get their user reference, and sending him/her a message, I get the user page-scoped id.

Using this user page-scoped id, I should be able to get the user app-scoped id, that I need to get more information from this user.

In order to to this, I use the facebook Matching API, and it works great for my administrator user, but as soon as I login using any other user, even if it is registered as a developer, the data that I get from the matching API is empty.

[https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/identity/id-matching]

Anybody has an idea about what could be happening here? My app is live (not approved), and I believe the permissions and tokens are right... If there is a problem, it should be about tokens, but I'm not sure about this.

Here, some of my code:

```
    const accessToken = config.facebook.unlimitedPageAccessToken;
  const clientSecret = config.facebook.clientSecret;
  const appsecretProof = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(accessToken, clientSecret).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);

request({
      url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/'+ recipientId +'/ids_for_apps',
      qs: { access_token: accessToken, appsecret_proof: appsecretProof }

    }, function (error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {

        body = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log("data --> " + JSON.stringify(body, null, 4));
        const userAppId = body.data[0].id;
        return userAppId;
      } else {
        console.error("Error trying to translate ID's.");
      }
    });
```

As I said, when I log in with any other user than the administrator, I get this:

```
{
  "data": []
}
```

Comment: Hi do you have any news I have the same problem but in the other way around. I have the `app scoped id` and I need to get `page scoped id`. It iw working for me but not for other users

Comment: Hi Leo. You need the user to have click on the "Begin" button on a chat with your page, or write a message to your page on this chat. Otherwise, you won't be able to get the user page scoped id, because it won't exist.

Comment: Oh ! Isn’t it the purpose of Facebook Matching ID ? To find PSID of users that log to your application thanks to Facebook login ?

Comment: Yes, that is the purpose, however both of these ID's wont exist until the user logs in (APP ID) or the user writes a message to your page (PSID), or the user clicks on any of the plugins provided for Messenger (PSID) (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/plugin-reference/)

Answer (score 1):

For every Facebook page, a user has a different psid. So until you get that page scoped id, you won't be able to send them a message. So may be what you can do is link the users to the page first to initialize the conversation.